# What does it mean that in a stock quote when there is no "Open" price?

Tags: investing

What does it mean when a stock has a "NO" open price?

http://ih.advfn.com/stock-market/USOTC/lithium-technology-corp-LTHUQ/stock-price

does this mean the stock is halted and could be investigated?

Comment: I invested in a small battery company and today the stock quotes shows no open price? http://investorshub.advfn.com/Lithium-Technology-Corporation-LTHUQ-5511/

Comment: By the way he q in the symbol indicates it's undergoing bankruptcy. If it opens at 0 then could it also mean there is no trading activity. But it could be other factors as well.

Comment: Not good news that there's no trading at all today on a company that averages 3 million shares a day.  There's no news to be found, and it's unlikely it would be halted for a full day for something ***good*** to be reported.  I hope you didn't buy much of it.

Answer (score 4):

As others have suggested in the comments, the opening price is normally the price of the first trade of the day.

This share did not trade today so there is no opening price.

Although the average daily trading volume is given as approximately 400,000, because the share price is a small fraction of a penny, this means that 400,000 shares trading is not necessarily a large number of trades.

On Friday, 30 September, there was a single trade and most days in the last couple of weeks have seen just 3 or 4 trades filled.

Therefore, it is not surprising to see a day with no trading activity if the number of trades per day is typically very small.  Since there is no trading activity, there is no opening price.

I'm sure I don't need to tell you about the risks of holding shares with no liquidity.  The bid price given on the linked site is $0.0001, so basically the shares have no buyers.  Finding a buyer for your shares may require patience and sacrifice.